# hello world compiled but error in running

Tags: cuda

I'm a newbie in learning cuda. I read "CUDA by Example" and trying to run my first program hello world. It was compiled but i don't know why I can't execute the binary:

```
tia@tia:~/Documents/Coba$ nvcc heloworld.cu -lcudart -o run

tia@tia:~/Documents/Coba$ ls
heloworld  heloworld~  heloworld.cu  run

tia@tia:~/Documents/Coba$ ./run
./run: error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone please help me how to fix this problem? Many thanks :)

Comment: @ChristianIrwanHadiWicaksana: its a runtime link loader error. How is source code going to help?

Answer (score 2):

The runtime error indicates that it could not find the cudart library. The path used to find libraries at runtime can be different from compile time since nvcc (which is on your path) knows where to look but the Linux OS needs to be told. Run the following before you execute:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path_to_cuda_libs>:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

See the section on environment variables in the [Getting Started Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html) for more information.

Assuming you have administrative privileges on this machine, you could also consider upgrading to the latest version of CUDA (5.5).